# get related videos from video id in you tube

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am trying to get the related videos of particular you tube video id in <kbd>php</kbd> but I'm not getting related videos of it.

below is the code. here video id is `TgPM519IBXw`.

#### Question :

*i want that when user click on particulate video than video related to clicked video should be display.*

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/TgPM519IBXw/related?v=2&alt=jsonc';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);
$info = $data["feed"];
$video = $info["entry"];
$nVideo = count($video);
print_r($video);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have the "path" to the video wrong.

Try this:

```
$items = $data['data']['items'];
$video = $items[0];
```

You should inspect the JSON structure before asking questions like this. You can easily see the structure by doing `var_dump($data)`.